# Rolling Ball Simulation

Tags: matlab, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a rolling ball in matlab where I need to be able to control it's movement across a 2d plane while also controlling it's pitch and roll.

I've figured out how to control it's pitch, roll and origin coordinates, however I can't think of a good way to do all three at once. What's happening is that I can control the pitch and roll by themselves just fine. However, when I add that to controlling the balls origin it shifts the entire plane that it 'rolls' on.

I figure that I could just go the hard route and change it's origin coordinates so that once the roll and pitch is added, it lands back on the flat plane. However, this seems rather overcomplicated and I figure that there has to be a better way of doing it.

```
clear;
clc;
rho = 100;
xCenter = 0;
yCenter = 0;
theta = 0 : 0.01 : 2*pi;
radius = 40;
x_del = radius * cos(theta) + xCenter;
y_del = radius * sin(theta) + yCenter;

freq=1;
t=0:0.001:1;
y_sin=sin(2*pi*freq*t);
x_cos=cos(2*pi*freq*t);

max_angle=0.5;

x_cos_adjusted=x_cos*max_angle;
y_sin_adjusted=y_sin*max_angle;

y_angle=asind(y_sin_adjusted);
x_angle=asind(x_cos_adjusted)*-1;

for n = 1:1000; 


  [x, y, z] = sphere (40);
  bb = surf (3*x+x_del(n), 3*y+y_del(n), 3*z);
  axis equal;

  xlim([-50 50])
  ylim([-50 50])
  zlim([-50 50])

  x_direction=[0 1 0];
  y_direction=[1 0 0];

  rotate(bb,x_direction,x_angle(n));
  rotate(bb,y_direction,y_angle(n));

  refresh()

  pause(0.01);

end
```

This code is intended to include orbit and precession without any elevation change

Note: I forgot to add that this is going to be taking input from a ps2 controller after I finish it. So, bonus points for making it easy to implement with that in mind.

Comment: Sorry about that, forgetting the clear made it run on old variables. Should run now.

Comment: Yes, working now